# How to limit the user's session duration

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible:
The wordpress website is for kids so I want to limit their website usage. I want them to be able to use the website for a number of hours per day, let's say 4 hours. After 4 hours, they are logged out of the website and they can only access it again the next day.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is use table for recording activities and sum them for everyday next use middleware to control user

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: if you can write plugin Wordpress use this [link](https://dev.to/christopherarter/middleware-for-wordpress-g4k)        or user this plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/only-one-device-login-limit/)

Comment: Thanks! For the plugin, how do I use it so that I can sum the daily activities?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement logic as below. code is not tested but it will help to implement logic.
on load, it will check for user is logged in or not.
If user is logged in then check for current time and last login time and do apply logic accordingly

```
add_action('init', 'check_login_logout');

function check_login_logout() {
 
   if(is_user_logged_in()) {
      
      $current_time = time();

      $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
      if($last_login)  {
        if( ($current_time - $last_login <= 24) && $current_time - $last_login > 4 ){
            wp_logout();
            header("Location: http://fubar.com/login/?logout=0");
            exit();
         }else if( ($current_time - $last_login > 24){
            $last_login = update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', $current_time);
         }
      }else{
         $last_login = update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', $current_time);
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: you need to define possible variables like `$user_id` and any other if needed

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a syntax error syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: in the line $last_login = update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', $current_time);